# MATLAB: How to change color of graph?

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

This is the question I need to answer:

[image]

So far my function only reads:

```
function eval = plotupc(x)
    bar(x, 'histc')
end
```

When I try to change the color of the graph, it stops my graph from being a histogram. Also, how can I make it so that my graph starts at 0 rather than 1?

Answer (score 1):

The [`bar` documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) states that

> **Note:** You cannot specify names and values when using hist or histc options.

Instead, you can set the x-axis locations and bar width manually:

```
bar(0.5:numel(x)-0.5, x, 1, 'k');   
axis tight;
```

The first argument gives the x locations of the bars; another example [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/bar.html#btj3hs7-1). Here the bars are shifted one half to the right.

The second argument is of course your input.

The third argument specifies the width of the bars, a width of 1 ensures that they touch.

The last argument, 'k' is for [key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model), i.e. black.

Finally, `axis tight` makes sure there is no leftover whitespace at the edges of the plot.

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

```
t=bar(0:1:length(x)-1,x,'histc');
set(t,'facecolor','k');
xlim([0 length(x)-1]);
```